# GreenPlum: SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Context should be init first (buffile.c:1025)

Tags: sql, greenplum

We are experiencing the following error in our Greenplum cluster having 16 segments while running a query having 10+ joins.

SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Context should be init first (buffile.c:1025)

Answer (score 0):

Would be good to provide reproduction information and follow along discussion for this issue here: https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/issues/10520